# sql query related with different table structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables,

- table A with column fields `id`,`code_id`, `claim_id`,
- table B with column fields `id`, `claim_id` ,`mem_id` and `p_id`,
- table C with `id`, `code_id`, `end_dt`, `order_id`, `strt_date`.

Now i have to select those claim_d from `table A` which are not in `table b` and insert those additional claim_id in `table C`. id is the primary key.structure for all table is different, can anyone let me know how to do this??

i got the additional rows from `table A` by following query:

```
select distinct ad.claim_id 
 FROM tableA a
 left join tableC c 
 on LEFT(c.CLAIM_ID,12) = a.Claim_id 
 where id is not null
```

then I am not sure how to add those columns in `tableB`??

Comment: Why do you left join A to C and not to B? "Now i have to select those claim_d from table A which are not in table b"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the user input, following is the proposed query:

```
   declare @outputTable table (id int, claimid varchar(50) not null)

   -- identify values from table A that are not in table B
   ;with cteClaimIdsInAButNotInB
   as
   (
     select
       a.claim_id, a.code_id
     from
       tableA a
       left outer join tableB b on 
           a.claim_id = b.claim_id
     where
       b.claim_id is null
   )

   -- Add these newly found values to tableB and get the id from it
   merge into tableB as b
   using cteClaimIdsInAButNotInB as cte
   on (b.claimid = cte.claimid)
   when not matched then
          insert(claimid) values(cte.claimid)
          output inserted.id, cte.claimid into @outputTable(id, claimid)

   -- Add these newly added values from tableB to tableC as well
   insert into tableC(id, claimid)
   select id, claimid from @outputTable
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. I tried the same logic but it says that data cannot be inserted as id in tableC cannot accept null values ??

Comment: my appologies, table A doesnot have id field just the claim_id and code_id??

Comment: can you post sample data?  Can you show us the table design in TSQL or SSMS snippet image.  Obviously, table C has some columns defined to not accept nulls.  The Common Table Expression is return a null value.

Comment: tableA : claimid(var(50),null) , claimln((var(50),null) , icd_id(var(50),null)                                                 tableB: id(PK, not null) , claimid(var(50),null), claimln(var(50),null)                                                   tableC: id(int, not null) , icd_id(var(50), not null)

Comment: tableA : claimid(var(50),null) , claimln((var(50),null) , icd_id(var(50),null)                                                 tableB: id(PK, not null) , claimid(var(50),null), claimln(var(50),null)                                                   tableC: id(int, not null) , icd_id(var(50), not null)               This is the structure of all the tables..pls let me know what can be possible?

Comment: Is the id in tableC an identity or does it take value from id in tableB ?

Comment: id in table B is the foreign key in table C

Comment: Was the updated query (with Merge statement) working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the code to use the correct fields ...

```
 ;
    with cteClaimIdsInAButNotInB
       as
       (
           select
               a.claim_id, a.code_id, a.id
           from
               tableA a
               left outer join tableB b on 
                   a.claim_id = b.claim_id
           where
               b.claim_id is null
       )

       insert into tableC (claim_id, code_id)
       select claim_id, code_id from cteClaimIdsInAButNotInB;
```